# How to parse as HTML tag from server.R in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

What I am trying to do is parse at HTML string returned from a reactive function from server.R.  I have tried for several days to solve this but no luck.  For instance, given the following **ui.R** file:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar( 
  headerPanel("Code"), 
  sidebarPanel(   
  ), 
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("code")
  )  
))
```

and **server.R** file:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$code <- renderText({   
    HTML('<strong> Hello World <strong>')
  }) 
})
```

I would like the output to be:

**Hello World**

Instead of the raw HTML text output showing the strong tag.

Essentially, I would like to have the HTML text parsed in the ui.R.  I am actually trying to do something more complex than this, but once I get this simple problem solved, I should be OK.  I can't just put the HTML tag within the ui.R, because I would like it to change based on some other values. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` instead of text

Comment: That worked, thanks! You are a savior!  I will post as an answer for the rest to see.

Answer (score 8):

All, I have found the solution thanks to kind soul over at StackOverflow.  You just use renderUI and uiOutput as such:

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$code <- renderUI({   
    HTML('<strong> Hello World <strong>')
  }) 
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar( 
  headerPanel("Code"), 
  sidebarPanel(   
  ), 
  mainPanel(
     uiOutput("code")
  )  
))
```

Question solved.